# How not to override property in CSS

Tags: css, background, overriding

i'm a beginner in HTML and CSS , i've set `:hover` pseudo class to all anchor tags in my site with `background-color` , but at a portion of my site , i need to have a `background-image` in `:hover` as well as the `background-color`.

But unfortunately the `:hover` class of that portion (`background-image`) is overriding the `background-color`, how to set both `background-color` and `background-image` without anyone overriding the other, so i get the global `background-color` with `background-image` in front of it?

Of course without writing a special :hover in that portion with background-color & image combined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specificity and the cascade are your friends. Your CSS rules for your anchors can be structured something like the following (use a class or ID to denote that specific portion of your site):

```
a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.some-portion a:hover {
    background-image: url(yourimg.png);
}
```

The second rule should still apply your background color because the color applies to *any anchor* on hover.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `!important` http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules, of course it would be helpful to see some example of how you are using it to give you more precise answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or id to your anchor that you want to be different.

```
<a id="differentTag" href="#">Link</a>
```

Then in your CSS...

```
#differentTag:hover {
    background-image: url(...);
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Hope that helps